# Who does the nameserver 4.2.2.2 belong to?

Tags: internet, nameserver, whois

Does someone know who is the owner of the Nameserver 4.2.2.2 ? I find a whois but I dont know the organisation.. Does someone know it ?

Has someone searched before?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You also like to ping it, don't you? :)

Comment: More/longer answers at http://serverfault.com/questions/132805/why-do-we-ping-the-ip-4-2-2-2-to-test-connectivity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's one of the Level3 nameservers (there's also 4.2.2.1, and 3-6 seem to work too).

They're a tier 1 transit provider, meaning that they own massive chunks of the internet's infrastructure and make money charging smaller providers (ISPs, hosts, resellers, etc.) to exchange data. You may not have heard of them but you've almost certainly used their services at some point without realising ;)

Comment: yeah - ISP to ISPs :)

Answer (score 15):

`4.2.2.2` is pretty long in the tooth.

If you're wondering why it has a PTR record of `gtei.net` then here's a little history.

1. It was originally owned and hosted by a provider called BBN Planet.
2. BBN was acquired by the General Telephone & Electronics Corporation in 1997 and became a sub-division of GTE known as GTE Internetworking. Hence the GTEI domain.
3. GTEI was spun off into a separate company called Genuity in 2000 when GTE was aquired by Verizon.
4. Genuity filed for bankruptcy in 2002 and was bought by Level 3.

Comment: 4.2.2.4 used to have a reverse DNS to i-will-not-steal-service.gtei.net

Comment: I'd heard recently that Level 3 were planning to restrict access to 4.2.2.1 and 4.2.2.2 from the wider internet, but I don't know how accurate that is.

Answer (score 0):

The truth is there is no official information on 4.2.2.1-6 on L3 sites. People use these cause these got famous. So I'm pretty sure if L3 decides to restrict public open access on it, its not going to happen too soon ;)